# Data visualisation tools availble on hive hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hql, hive, data-visualization

Please suggest some visualisation tools which can work on Hive-Hadoop.

The only thing is, it should accept **Hive** .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends what type of data analysis and visualization you have in mind.

If you intend to use a proprietary tool, then [Tableau](http://www.tableausoftware.com/solutions/hadoop-analysis) is one of among many other [options](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071233/open-source-tools/7-tools-for-taming-big-data-with-hadoop.html).

If you prefer tools that are open source (free and multi-platform), then you should consider using:

- [HUE Beeswax](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zq9PiKQ_hC8)
- [HBase Pig](http://gethue.tumblr.com/post/64707633719/hadoop-tutorial-use-pig-and-hive-with-hbase)
- [Google Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/)
- [ColorBrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/)
- [R](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9239723/Beginner_s_guide_to_R_Painless_data_visualization_)
- [Qt/QML](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cr80RKiEKvk)
- [Octave](http://www.ncnr.nist.gov/resources/tk_octave/)
- [OpenGL](http://www.atheiss.com/blog/c/data-visualization-opengl-simple-visualization-example/153)

Hive will not block you from using any of those tools for data visualization, as long as you know how to manipulate your data and how to work with the respective toll for analysis/visualization of your data.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the nascent Zeppelin project ( http://zeppelin-project.org )

Answer (score 1):

You can use elasticsearch's kibana(I'd prefer v3). That is;

1. Create an external table in Hive, which uses elasticsearch. Just as exaplained in:    https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/hive.html
2. Insert your data into this external table.
3. Point your kibana to your elasticsearch.
4. In kibana select the index/type and create your own dashboard.