# How can I visualize hive data?

Tags: hadoop, hive, visualization, tableau-api

I need a way to visualize data present in hive. I am running a custom multi node hadoop cluster with two slaves(datanode) and a master(namenode) on centOS. I already tried tableau but it is only compatible with packaged clusters like cloudera,hortonworks,etc. but not a custom cluster like mine.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can visualize the output of hive with Zeppelin Which is an open source Big data visualization platform by Apache foundation. You can deploy zeppelin on your name node and you can run hive queries through zeppelin.

You can refer to [this blog](https://acadgild.com/blog/data-visualization-using-apache-zeppelin/) for detailed information on how to install and integrate hive with zeppelin

Comment: I tried  installing zeppelin using the steps mentioned on your blog , but i am facing some issues. Can you please have a look at it. Here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42995566/hive-interpreter-not-found-in-zeppelins-jdbc-interpreter).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [Hue](http://gethue.com/) and [zeppelin](http://zeppelin-project.org/) - they  can be simply configured for custom cluster.

Answer (score 0):

[Hue](http://gethue.com/)

Hue is an open source Web interface for analyzing data with any Apache Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

Please see: [Data visualisation tools availble on hive hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296953/data-visualisation-tools-availble-on-hive-hadoop)

CMD line: Beeline 
Tools: Teradata SQL assistant, Squirrel SQL...

UI:
Ambari Views, Zeppelin, Lumify...

I need to test your comment about Tableau only working with HDP or Cloudera...