# Interpreter hive not found in zeppelin's jdbc interpreter

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, apache-zeppelin

I have installed zeppelin on my centOS system. It is not listing hive under JDBC interpreter.

I have hive installed on my system. Hive metastore and hiveserver2 are running. HIVE_HOME and HADOOP_HOME are set correctly.

Error on Zeppelin editor :

```
paragraph_1490339323949_-1789938581's Interpreter hive not found
```

Error in Zeppelin log files :

```
ERROR [2017-03-24 15:56:18,913] ({qtp1566723494-18} NotebookServer.java[afterStatusChange]:2018) - Error
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: paragraph_1490346145929_-1782899327's Interpreter hive not found
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Note.run(Note.java:572)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.socket.NotebookServer.persistAndExecuteSingleParagraph(NotebookServer.java:1626)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.socket.NotebookServer.runParagraph(NotebookServer.java:1600)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.socket.NotebookServer.onMessage(NotebookServer.java:263)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.socket.NotebookSocket.onWebSocketText(NotebookSocket.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.JettyListenerEventDriver.onTextMessage(JettyListenerEventDriver.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.message.SimpleTextMessage.messageComplete(SimpleTextMessage.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.AbstractEventDriver.appendMessage(AbstractEventDriver.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.JettyListenerEventDriver.onTextFrame(JettyListenerEventDriver.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.AbstractEventDriver.incomingFrame(AbstractEventDriver.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketSession.incomingFrame(WebSocketSession.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.extensions.ExtensionStack.incomingFrame(ExtensionStack.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.Parser.notifyFrame(Parser.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.Parser.parse(Parser.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.readParse(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillable(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: have you set the following setting https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/interpreter/hive.html

Comment: Do I need to manually set these properties? Zeppelin should have detected hive and hiveserver2 and set the corresponding properties accordingly. Anyway, I will try manually setting it.

Comment: Yes when i was installing i got the same problem so i set manually

Comment: Nope. It didn't work.

Comment: I need to set it on the zeppelin web UI's interpreter page only or in any config file as well?

Comment: ./bin/install-interpreter.sh --all <-- Did you executed this command https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/manual/interpreterinstallation.html

Comment: yep.. executed it.

Comment: Can you update the questions so we get to know whats the error ?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: you need to use %jdbc  as your interpreter and query your hive tables.see this blog for example http://sachinhingmire27.blogspot.in/2017_03_01_archive.html

Comment: %jdbc worked . Thanks a lot :D . I think you should write this as an answer to this question.

Comment: I have written the answer to the post please accept and vote if my answer helped you!!...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve the above issue by :-

1) setting the following properties [zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/interpreter/hive.html](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/interpreter/hive.html) for jdbc interpreter.

2) using  %jdbc as an Interpreter

```
%jdbc select date
```

**Hope this Helps!!!...**